# Нужно ли прятать абсолютные пути к файлам в php?

Tags: php, исключения, безопасность, пути

Обычно различного рода экзепшенами стараются закрыть внутренние ошибки.
Приведу примитивный пример, чтобы понятнее была суть вопроса.

```
$rand = rand(0, 1);
if ($rand == 1) $arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
printElements($arr);

function printElements(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $value) echo "$value<br/>";
}
```

В таком случае, если в `$rand` окажется `1`, скрипт выполнится без ошибок. Если же `0`, пользователь в браузере увидит что-то в духе

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to printElements()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /path/to/my/project/dir/index.php on line 5 and defined in
>   /path/to/my/project/dir/index.php:12 Stack trace: #0
>   /path/to/my/project/dir/index.php(5): printElements(NULL) #1 {main}
>   thrown in /path/to/my/project/dir/index.php on line 12.

Теперь он знает абсолютный путь к файлу, его название, название класса (если есть) и метода, в котором возникло исключение.

Отлавливаются такие ошибки при помощи <s>нормального кода</s> `try...catch`, это ясно.

Собственно, вопрос. Нужно ли усиленно отлавливать ошибки, выдающие абсолютные пути к файлам? Чем это может грозить в плане безопасности? Насколько это критично и как злоумышленники могут этим воспользоваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само по себе раскрытие полного пути является скорее "недостатком", чем опасной уязвимостью.

Но очень важно понимать, многие **критические уязвимости** конкретной системы складываются из **совокупности присутствующих недостатков**. Такие недостатки могут быть относительно безобидны сами по себе, но, в комбинации друг с другом, приводят к печальным последствиям.

Так, например, раскрытие абсолютных путей делает на несколько порядков более опасным случаи с LFI или SQL-инъекциями (используем load_file). Ведь теперь не нужно угадывать пути: знание расположения файлов позволит вам выгрузить исходный код приложения, скачать пользовательские файлы, и, возможно, даже получить шелл на атакуемом сервере.

В принципе, можно представить себе случаи, когда между уязвимостью с относительно небольшим импактом и полным контролем сервера стоит именно [full path disclosure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Full_Path_Disclosure).

Answer (score 1):

А зачем на проде исключения показывать?

Вы должны их ловить к примеру через функцию [set_exception_handler](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php):

```
set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
  echo "Текст ошибки: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
});
```

Теперь пользователи будут видеть только что случилось, а трейс вы должны логировать и уже по логам смотреть что случилось.

Comment: Есть масса способов прятать ошибки - начиная от вездесущих проверок валидности данных и заканчивая приведённым вами примером, но мой вопрос заключался в том, **насколько безопасно светить абсолютными путями**. Что может случиться, если кто-нибудь увидит такие подробности?

Comment: @nikitar ну смотря кто увидит, в любом случае это плохо для сайта и отношения к нему.